# Jetty URL rewrite/redirect strips query string

Tags: java, jetty, url-rewriting, embedded-jetty

I am currently struggling with Jettys [rewrite mechanisms](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler). Basically I want the URL
    `http://localhost:8080/membership/payment?id=5000` to be replaced by `http://localhost:8080/#/membership/payment?id=5000`

My current approach looks like this:

```
RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();
rewrite.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
rewrite.setRewritePathInfo(true);
rewrite.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");

RewriteRegexRule replace = new RewriteRegexRule();
replace.setRegex("/membership/(.*)");
replace.setReplacement("/#/membership/$1");
rewrite.addRule(replace);
```

In general this is working, the only thing missing is the query string (?id=5000) to be passed over to the new location.

How can I keep the query string even for the new location?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution to that:

```
private static ContextHandlerCollection prepareContexts() {

    MovedContextHandler handler = new MovedContextHandler();
    handler.setContextPath("/membership");
    handler.setNewContextURL("/#/membership");
    handler.setPermanent(true);
    handler.setDiscardPathInfo(false);
    handler.setDiscardQuery(false);

    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setServer(server);
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
    webAppContext.setWar("src/main/webapp");

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { handler, webAppContext });

    return contexts;
}
```

And afterwards the contexts have to be assigned:

```
server.setHandler(prepareContexts();
```